# Bone Inhereited rotation value

Tags: rigging, interface, drivers

So, simple question. I need both the inherited rotation and the actual rotation of a bone in order to make a driver for a texture. Trouble is I can't find where blender stores the inherited rotation values of a bone for. Found the values for the individual rotation of a bone in the bone properties tab (see image below); just need the same for what a bone inherits from its parent bones, but I can't find where that would be in the UI.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Each bone's rotation is inherited->inverse->local rotation; this can be chained along any number of bones.  Inherited rotation + local rotation isn't enough to give you the full orientation of any bone, and there can be any number of steps of inheritance.  Probably, you want the rotation of the bone in some other space?  Probably, world space?  You can specify world space in your driver's variables' fields for "transformation" type variables (not for single property variables.)

Comment: World Space driver did the trick, thanks